# A riddle worksheet

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I've made a riddle worksheet for you, this is all my stuff I made, and this is a moderately hard multi - step puzzle so don't expect to get it within 3 minutes. Happy Puzzling!

[image: the worksheet]

Hint:

> Maybe I could encrypt things twice in two different ways...

Comment: Is it important to the puzzle that it's rotated 90 degrees? If not, it seems like it would be more polite to put it the right way up.

Comment: It's upside down now? That can't be right.

Comment: Finally, I've done it.

Comment: @punpun1000 Well done all of you, together you all solved it! It’s nice to see 3 SE puzzling people all contributing and adding to each other’s ideas! Thank you all for answering my question!

Comment: @Weather Vane Please read the comment above

Comment: @Naeem Shaikh please read the top comment

Comment: @RohitJose.. there was no clue about Vigenere Cipher in the worksheet though..

Comment: Hmmm, I though you might think to use it with moth as a keyword because I circled it and drew an arrow towards the text with it... sorry if it was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is

> nocebo

This answer relied heavily on the answers from @WeatherVane and @NaeemShaikh

The crossword was solved by those two, with the values of the numbered positions being

> 1: T, 2: H, 3: O, 4: M

The number on the left side indicates the reordering giving us the word

> moth

We can then decrypt the bottom text

> Using a Vigenere Cipher with the key moth, the input of LVHVSFJONFQCDCROSZPDWVYYSVECCFYOQFPOACIOIYWDIFSSC becomes ZHOOGRQHBRXVROYHGLWWKHFRGHLVQRFHERWHOOPHWKDWWRZLQ

As referenced by the "Et tu Brutus"

> We can decrypt that string with a Caeser Cipher.  A decryption using a 3 letter shift gives us welldoneyousolveditthecodeisnocebotellmethattowin

which can be rewritten as

> Well done, you solved it.  The code is nocebo.  Tell me that to win.

Comment: Well done you! It took two other people to do this and finally you!

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

> [image]

Also the phrase:

> Et Tu Brutus, is a Latin phrase meaning "even you, Brutus?" It is notable for its occurrence in William Shakespeare's play Julius Caesar, where it is spoken by the Roman dictator Julius Caesar to his friend Marcus Junius Brutus at the moment of Caesar's assassination. This means decrypt using **Caeser** cipher.
> The note points that 4312 is the key for this cipher, and so far the crossword yields **MO*H**. which might mean **moth**, **mosh** or **moch**, but i am not yet able to decrypt using that as a key for Caeser cipher.

Comment: Well done, but what about the title? The title is key to all. (That isn't a reference to the vigenere cipher.) Also: yummy yummy I like eating mashrooms :P

Answer (score 2):

If seems to be OK to post partial solutions. I had already got as far as @NaeemShaikh before he posted but can't solve the whole puzzle. However I suggest that the title is

> bones(skeleton)

because

> **fxryrgba** is the basic rot13 Caesar cypher for **skeleton** which is also a play on the word **key**.

The answer to 4 down is

> **title** because it fits the evidence and OP hinted at it under NS's answer.

I have a suspicion that the puzzle has

> a *hand written* message so that one **U** can be written as a **V** (as was done in Latin) without it being too obvious.

I can't figure out what the

> **1234567890** and **uSe iT** are for, although I have tried numerous keys for the vigenere cypher. It's not the basic Caesar cypher, I tried all 25 shifts.

Comment: Very well done! A quick word of advice: RED HERRINGS! Also: filling in 4 down for the crossword means what? Also also: who says I have to use just one level of encryption  YOU ARE THE CLOSEST TO THE ANSWER! KEEP IT UP! I am expecting great things from you, Weather Vane!

Comment: Thank you I already suspected there were some pickles in the barrel, and your other XYZ comment. I saw my score rise by 15 and then go back down so ...

Comment: Back down so? I wouldn’t know why anyone would downvote your post. Also: what you thought was bones stood for rot13 (often seen in the comments)

Comment: I meant perhaps +15 for correct answer and -15 for changing your mind. Obviously, this is not the correct answer - yet.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused for a second and thought you’d solved it. You almost have though.